# How to write large dataset to csv file in pieces using nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, csv

Hi so I am working on a file that reads in a large set of data from a database. Then I use a module called json2csv in nodejs that converts the data set and writes it to a csv file. Here is the link for the json2csv module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv 
Using this module it converts the data into csv data but the problem I am having is that when it starts to write to file since the data set is soo big it runs out of memory and crashes. Is there any way that I can write a small chunk of the data instead of writing all of it? Here is what I have so far.

```
    /*require the ibm_db module*/
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
var fs    = require("fs");
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var db2query = "SELECT DISTINCT DISCEVNT.EVENT_RUNID, DISCEVNT.EVENT_TIME, DISCEVNT.EVENT_SEVERITY, DISCEVNT.EVENT_ATTRIBUTE, DISCEVNT.EVENT_DESC, DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP.DE_IP, DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP.DE_HOSTNAME, DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP.DE_FQDN, DISCRUN.SERVERID_X FROM (DB2INST2.DISCEVNT DISCEVNT INNER JOIN DB2INST2.DISCRUN DISCRUN ON (DISCEVNT.EVENT_RUNID = DISCRUN.DISCOVERRUNID_X)) INNER JOIN DB2INST2.DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP ON (DISCEVNT_ATTR_IP.DE_ATTR = DISCEVNT.EVENT_ATTRIBUTE) WHERE (DISCEVNT.EVENT_RUNID BETWEEN 2017071400000000 AND 2017071900000000) ORDER BY DISCEVNT.EVENT_TIME ASC;";
var db2setup = "DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=CMDB;UID=user;PWD=password!;HOSTNAME=localhost;port=3000";
var dataJson = [];
var fields = ['EVENT_RUNID','EVENT_TIME','EVENT_SEVERITY','EVENT_ATTRIBUTE','EVENT_DESC','DE_IP','DE_HOSTNAME','DE_FQDN','SERVERID_X'];
console.log("Test program to access DB2 sample database");

/*Connect to the database server
  param 1: The DSN string which has the details of database name to connect to, user id, password, hostname, portnumber
  param 2: The Callback function to execute when connection attempt to the specified database is completed
*/
function getData(values){
    dataJson = values;
    console.log(dataJson);
    var csv = json2csv({ data: dataJson, fields: fields });
    console.log("CSV data:");
    console.log(csv[0]);
    console.log(csv.length);
    console.log(dataJson.length);
    console.log(dataJson[0]);
    fs.writeFile('C:\\Users\\ztaddmusr\\Desktop\\CSV FILES\\file.csv', csv, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('file saved');
    });

  }

ibmdb.open(db2setup, function(err, conn)
{
        if(err) {
        /*
          On error in connection, log the error message on console
        */
            console.error("error: ", err.message);
        } else {

        /*
            On successful connection issue the SQL query by calling the query() function on Database
            param 1: The SQL query to be issued
            param 2: The callback function to execute when the database server responds
        */
        conn.query(db2query, function(err, data) {

        if(err) {
        /*
          On error in connection, log the error message on console
        */
            console.error("error: ", err.message);
        } else {
            //console.log(data);

            getData(data);
            console.log('Data finished retrieving from the datatbase. Now will write to file.')

        }
            /*
                Close the connection to the database
                param 1: The callback function to execute on completion of close function.
            */
            conn.close(function(){
                console.log("Connection Closed");
            });
        });
    }
});
//var csv = json2csv({ data: dataJson, fields: fields });
//console.log(csv);
//fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
//  if (err) throw err;
//  console.log('file saved');
//});
```

I had been trying to use a loop but kept messing up. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: try to use nodejs streams

Comment: @Trufa here is the error                                                                          if (str !== '') {
          ^

RangeError: Invalid string length                                                                    I know this is because of the memory becasue when i seect less rows it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generators if using ES6 with an implementation such as co(npm package). Then you can halt the execution of asynchronous code according to partitions, and append to file using chunks.

Something like this(haven't compiled it; there may be errors):

```
function* writeToCsv(csvObj){
  let chunkedArr = chunkify(csvObj);
  chunkedArr.forEach(co.wrap(chunk => {
    co.wrap(writeChunkToCsv(chunk))(dir)  
  }))
}

function* writeChunkToCsv(chunk){
  return dir => {
    yield fs.writeFile(dir, csv);
  }
}

function chunkify(arr, partitions){ 
  let ansArr = [];
  for(let i = 0, currentArr = []; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(i%(arr.length/partitions) === 0 || i === arr.length){
      ansArr = ansArr.push([...currentArr]);
      currentArr = [];
    }
    else{
      currentArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return ansArr;
}
```

Comment: You can also use async await or make an implementation to run asynchronous synchronously(especially for ES versions less than 6). Generators are one way to do it.